# Server returned an invalid or incomplete response

Tags: php, laravel

My site was working from last 6 months and suddenly I got that error after login to the web application, then after whenever I hit that url in the browser then login page does not display and it shows me a message "502 bad gateway"

The error message is:

> 502 bad gateway the server returned an invalid or incomplete response
>   PHP

Comment: 502 usually means that u have sent a request to some other server(maybe for login or post login). Please check these dependencies for further troubleshooting

Comment: Do you manage the server or is it managed by a hoster?

Comment: You might get more help on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Do you use a third part service to login?